# How do I post-process rviz images?

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz

I've made a gazebo envirnment and successfully visualized the cam image with rviz. However I wanted to do some post process to make it simulate the result of image segmentation and send it back to rviz. Is there any similiar methods or tutorials for this? Maybe a way to import the node to python?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* brian2lee, but I'm afraid that questions asking for code are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given coding problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so please try to include what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask], [about] and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for advice on writing a good question.

Comment: I apologized for the trouble. Just starting to learn the gazebo, ros, rviz related things. After running into and posting several problems, I felt like it would be better to ask for some tutorials to follow. Will beware of the regulations more in the future.

Comment: You should decide what you are trying to accomplish with the simulation. If it's just an effect for rviz then you could [make a plugin](https://github.com/ros-visualization/visualization_tutorials) that does the image processing you want. You could also just read a sample image from a file and publish that for visualization in rviz, or you could write a [subscriber and publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29) pair that subscribe to your image topic, apply some modification, and publish the modified result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many nice tutorials that you could follow. I am listing down some of them below:

http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc

https://roboticsbackend.com/ros-import-python-module-from-another-package/

And for the last part of your question, see this.

https://gist.github.com/zkytony/fb7616b745d77025f6abe919c41f8ea4

Comment: Thanks for the help. These tutorial seems helpful. Might have to spend plenty of time looking into them.

Comment: I would appreciate if you upvote it :)

Comment: Oops sorry, thanks for the help again.

Comment: This *seems* like a [link only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) answer... if the links die, then the answer will not be much use. Please read [What is Stack Overflow's take on link only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168712/280335)

Comment: It is a (collection of) link-only answers, but there's no good way to avoid that other than republishing the entire tutorial here. What's more, there's nothing saying that any one tutorial is "correct," so if someone else posts an answer with *three* tutorials does that get accepted? What about one tutorial in C++? It's a question that's asking for opinions/lists, so it's off-topic. There's no specific question to answer, so there's no *knowledge* to impart.